# Jenkins with github bug payload

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have a problem I can not solve on implementation with github jenkins builds do not engage is incomprehensible!

- I use the **github jenkins plugin** to automatically configure github rest.
- I have disabled all security rights + **cross fire** to be sure it goes
- In the configuration of the job, I have e**nabled wipe out & Strength clone repository** and **Build When a change is pushed to GitHub**
- I configured the branch ****** for ca build all branches

When I look at the logs jenkins, I have

Granting READ access for github-webhook url: /github-webhook/

May 26, 2014 12:19:49 PM INFO com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubWebHook processGitHubPayload

Received POST for https://github.com/myRepo/repo

May 26, 2014 12:19:49 PM INFO com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubWebHook processGitHubPayload

Considering to poke CC
May 26, 2014 12:19:49 PM INFO com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubWebHook processGitHubPayload

Poked CC

But the build does not start I do not understand! How please?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't not get all your infos, sorry.

which option of jeckins have you enable after linking your repository ?

Personnaly, I have ticked something like (sorry for translation) :

> Periodicly looking to git repo

and I had a cron tasks : ***/5 * * * ***

This looks the git repo for a commit every 5 minutes.

Comment: After analysis, I assume that you missed what I just wrote, that is the event that triggers the build.

What you configured is how jenkins acts with GIT, and, in your case, every build will force a clone of the repository.